# How can I get a new IP from DHCP?

Tags: ubuntu-10.10, dhcp

I connect to internet via my dorm's ethernet and IP addresses are assigned by DHCP. I tried

```
sudo dhclient -r
dhclient
```

but that doesn't work. are there another commands i can issue?

p.s: I don't want to get a static IP, just get a new one.

Comment: I must ask _why_ do you want a different address?

Comment: sites like rapidshare, fileserve etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is entirely up to the DHCP server. It probably will give you (the MAC address owner) the same address as long as the lease has not yet passed its expiration time.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your /etc/network/interfaces file has a line similar to this:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Use this command to restart networking (and request DHCP IP in the process.)

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

You can also use this command to request DHCP: [Ubuntu Request DHCP](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/dhcping.8.html)